# Kotlin best way to log using slf4j

Tags: spring-boot, logging, kotlin, slf4j

I have an spring boot project with default log configuration using logback. I have always used this approach for logging purpose inside my applications:

```
logger.info("Get user paginated: filter {}",user)
```

Now i am learning Kotlin and I was reading about String templates.If i rewrite my sentence using $ would be:

```
logger.info("Get user paginated: filter $user")
```

Which would be the better way to log in Kotlin with Spring boot?

Comment: See also https://realjenius.com/2017/08/31/logging-in-kotlin/

Answer (score 30):

The better way is neither; add https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging and write

```
logger.info { "Get user paginated: filter $user" }
```

with the advantages of both.

Comment: I get the advantage of the lambda, to delay string concatenation and toString calls until actually needed. But what's the (performance) advantage of the String template? Or is it just readability?

Comment: The point is that using a string template in `logger.info("Get user paginated: filter $user")` comes with a performance _dis_-advantage; in Kotlin-Logging it doesn't. So you get both the readability advantage of the string template and the performance advantage of not constructing the message if it isn't needed.

Answer (score 12):

The point of the `{}` syntax supported by SLF4J is to avoid useless String concatenation and toString() calls if the log message is never actually generated (for example because the level is higher than info.

A template string doesn't avoid that: the `user.toString()` method needs to be called, and its result needs to be appended to the static part of the log message, before being passed to `logger.info()`.

So, if you're looking for the best performance, use SL4J parameters. If you don't care and find the template string more readable, use the template string.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Slf4j-templates with `{}` and if you don't want to add an extra dependency you can add [my simple kotlin-slf4j-extension](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-samples/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/org/slf4j/LoggerExtension.kt) to your project to support the kotlin style efficiently:

```
private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

fun log() {
    log.trace { "trace message" }
    log.debug { "debug message" }
    log.info { "info  message" }
    log.warn { "warn  message" }
    log.error { "error message" }
    log.error(IllegalStateException("throwable message")) { "exception" }
}
```

[Slf4k](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-samples/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/log/Slf4k.kt) is an alternative implementation that does not use kotlin extensions.

```
val log = Slf4k.getLogger {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)
fun testing() {
      logger.info(ctx.toString())
      logger.error(err.message)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).